# Minecraft stops responding when any system-related key is pressed

Tags: keyboard, java, freeze, minecraft

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 an have been playing Minecraft, but whenever i press any system related key (that is not also used by Minecraft (Alt, Volume up, Volume down, etc.)). Minecraft window "minimizes" but it seems, like i can still press stuff in Minecraft. Alt+f4, Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+W or even holding f3+c doesn't close Minecraft.
This problem completely freezes not just Minecraft but also Ubuntu.